# Creating a hanging indent without changing the bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I am working on my thesis and I am having trouble with a formatting issue. I have been given a template that is a bit outdated to the current thesis format standards for my university. Currently the bibliography section is not using hanging indents. I am using the SIAM bibliography style and do not wish to change it so that I can remain as close to the current format as possible.

How would I modify the main.txt or the cls file so that I can get hanging indents?

Currently I am only able to change the indentation on the first line of each entry. This is my modification so far.

UTRGVthesis.cls::626

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
      {\doublespacing
      \chapter*{\bibname}%
      \singlespacing
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \vspace{-42pt}  % makes space between title and text zero
      \vspace{2\baselineskip}  % add two blank line spaces
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
            \setlength\itemindent{1in}% Adjust this value to change indent amount
            \setlength\labelwidth{\itemindent}%
            \advance\leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

[Here](https://github.com/UTRGV-SMSS/Thesis-Template) is the template I am using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Do you employ a citation management package, say, `cite` or `natbib`? Please advise.

Comment: No, I do not employ any citation management packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \chapter*{\bibname}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
\normalsize\list{}{%
  \usecounter{enumi}%
  \leftmargin 1em\itemindent -1em\parsep \z@\partopsep\z@%
    \itemsep\z@%
 }}%
{\endlist}%
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just reduces the indent on the first line. I need to keep the indent on the first line the same and increase the indent on the following lines.